# Setting up a large Xcode project

Tags: xcode

I have a large exiting C++ project involving:

- 4 applications
- 50+ libraries
- 20+ third party libraries

It all builds fine on Windows using VS8, Linux using QMake (project uses Qt a lot). I also build it on OS X using QMake but I was wanting to setup an Xcode project to handle it in an IDE. I'm struggling to setup proper configuration to easily define dependencies, both to internal libraries and to the third party. I can do property sheets and .pri files in my (disturbed) sleep, but would appreciate some advice on building such large projects in Xcode.

I've been experiencing with Xcode configuration files and #including one from another but it does not seem to work as I would expect, especially when defining standard locations for header files etc.

Is there some good book describing the process of setting up Xcode (remember it's C++, I'm not wanting to learn ObjC at this time)?

Or maybe a good open source project I could learn from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Step in to Xcode](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334221) may be the book you're looking for. It's got a whole section devoted to using AppleScript to automate configuration includes. I've been going through the book myself on O'Reilly Safari as I've found myself in a situation similar to yourself!

Comment: Be forewarned though, The applescript implementation in XCode4 is currently horribly broken. (I'm assuming that book was written in the XCode3 era)